# How do I turn a comma separated string field into an Array in MongoDB?

Tags: arrays, string, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have three documents that looks like this:

```
_id: ObjectId('61e1312ad435c7124aa883a1')
name: "Brian"
languages: "English,Spanish,French"

_id: ObjectId('52e1312ad435c7124aa883a2')
name: "Max"
languages: "English"

_id: ObjectId('37e1312ad435c7124aa883a9')
name: "Mike"
languages: ""
```

As you can see, the **languages** field can either be empty, have one item, or multiple items separated by commas.

How can I turn the **languages** field into an Array? The end result should look like this:

```
_id: ObjectId('61e1312ad435c7124aa883a1')
name: "Brian"
languages: [
    "English",
    "Spanish",
    "French"
]

_id: ObjectId('52e1312ad435c7124aa883a2')
name: "Max"
languages: [
    "English"
]

_id: ObjectId('37e1312ad435c7124aa883a9')
name: "Mike"
languages: []
```

Comment: Update/Aggregate?

Comment: Not sure what you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [$split](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/split/) to do this, like so:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      "languages": {
        $filter: {
          input: {
            $split: [
              "$languages",
              ","
            ]
          },
          cond: {
            $gt: [
              {
                $strLenCP: "$$this"
              },
              0
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/p-oQlBy1kO8)

If you want to update the entire collection you can use the same pipelined within an update with the "pipelined update" syntax:

```
db.collection.updateMany(
{},
[
  {
    "$set": {
      "languages": {
        $filter: {
          input: {
            $split: [
              "$languages",
              ","
            ]
          },
          cond: {
            $gt: [
              {
                $strLenCP: "$$this"
              },
              0
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```